# Add route inside runApp() with data from textfield?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

So i was exploring flutter web and come to know that i can extend url in the url bar by creating routes in my runApp() method inside main();

Like this :

```
void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new SplashScreen(),
    routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
      '/homepage': (BuildContext context) => new MyHomePage(),
   // '/resultpage': (BuildContext context) => new resultpage(searchText: ????? ),
    },
  ));
}
```

Here `searchText` inside `resultPage()` is the textfield whose input is taken from textfield in `MyHomePage()`.

I can see homepage at my local url like this:

> http://127.0.0.1:8080/#/homepage

So the problem is at this time i dont know the value of searchtext and cant understand how can i show resultpage url.

I am using push like this:

`Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');`

Can I add routes from homePage or is there any other method to do it?
Also is it possible to add searchText in the name of that route??

Please let me know if you require more info. Thanks

Comment: Have you seen this? https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

Comment: I tried  onGenerate()  method in materialApp(), arguments are passing but pagename is not present. i,e., i cant see the page name in url.